# How can I send the data in one large email vs multiple smaller emails?

Tags: perl, email, smtp

This section of my script sends the emails out to myself from a test email address, I need to have the email formatted like this:

$keyname  $keyexpr  $keycount  $keyavailable

$keyname  $keyexpr  $keycount  $keyavailable

$keyname  $keyexpr  $keycount  $keyavailable

$keyname  $keyexpr  $keycount  $keyavailable...etc

Instead, I receive several emails with just one line of data instead of multiple. How would I do this?

```
if ($debug and !$hidestdout) {
                $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($mailhost, Debug => 1);
                }
                else {
                $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($mailhost);
                }
                eval {
                    $smtp->mail($mailfrom) || die("$!\n");
                    if ($smtp->to(split(/,/, $mailto))) {
                        $smtp->data();
                        $smtp->datasend("Subject: License File Status Report\n");
                        $smtp->datasend("\n");                                                    
                        $smtp->datasend("\t$keyname  $keyexpr  $keycount  $keyavailable\n");
                        $smtp->dataend();
                    } else {
                        print "\tERROR SENDING EMAIL, RUN WITH DEBUG FOR MORE INFO: ", $smtp->message();
                        print "\tCHECK MAIL KEYWORDS: mailhost=$mailhost | mailfrom=$mailfrom | mailto=$mailto\n\n";
                        print LOGFILE "ERROR SENDING EMAIL, RUN WITH DEBUG FOR MORE INFO: ", $smtp->message() if ($log ne "");
                        print LOGFILE "  RUN WITH DEBUG, CHECK MAIL KEYWORDS: mailhost=$mailhost | mailfrom=$mailfrom | mailto=$mailto\n" if ($log ne "");
                    }
                    $smtp->quit;
                };
                if  ($@) {
                    print "\tERROR SENDING EMAIL, RUN WITH DEBUG FOR MORE INFO\n";
                    print "\tCHECK MAIL KEYWORDS: mailhost=$mailhost | mailfrom=$mailfrom | mailto=$mailto\n\n";
                    print LOGFILE "ERROR SENDING EMAIL, RUN WITH DEBUG FOR MORE INFO\n" if ($log ne "");
                    print LOGFILE "  CHECK MAIL KEYWORDS: mailhost=$mailhost | mailfrom=$mailfrom | mailto=$mailto\n" if ($log ne "");
                }
```

Comment: The code you show seems to send an email, with that one line.  If all this is in a loop where those variables are changed thus making a new  line of data, then of course it will send separate emails.  You should first assemble all data (in that loop which I presume is around this), _then_ send an email with all of it.

Comment: @Filburt Couldn't I also dump an array out in the $smtp->datasend field? The only way I've used dump is dump(@arr);

Comment: Well, yes, something like that.  But why with `dump`? Build a string out of (all) your data and submit that with `datasend`. Like, `my $data = join '\n', @all_data` and then `datasend($data)`. I am not sure but `datasend` may also take an arrayref.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by concatenating the data the variables grabbed and assigning that to another variable, which would then be called in the "email body".

```
$mail_body .= "\t$keyname  $keyexpr  $keycount  $keyavailable\n";
```

...

```
$smtp->datasend("\t $mail_body \n");
```

After all of the data was now within the email message, outside of the loop is where I ended and quit the email.

Thanks for the help everyone!